# knockout data-bind html with having inner data-bind

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Here is my html looks like:

```
<div class="xyz-template" data-bind="html:myViewModel().htmlTemplate"></div>
```

And I would like to have data-bind in htmlTemplate itself:
here is my knockout:

```
function myViewModel() {
    self.htmlTemplate = ko.observable();
    self.initialize = function ()
 {
        self.htmlTemplate(`
          <p data-deId="de-box-5" data-bind="html: myViewModel().getDynamicContent()">
            Initial content
          </p>
        `);
 };

self.getDynamicContent = function()
{
   return "dynamic content";
};

};
```

Well the return value is

```
Initial content
```

How can I have inner bind in binding html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knockout: Best Way To Create Links In Rendered Content Bound To ViewModel Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618257/knockout-best-way-to-create-links-in-rendered-content-bound-to-viewmodel-functi)

Answer (score 0):

Whole trick is around rebinding your view. `ko` does not allow to call `applyBindings` twice on the same node, so you need to `cleanNode` from bindings and apply it to element.

Here is the working scenario:

```js
function myViewModel() {
  let self = this
  
  self.htmlTemplate = ko.observable();
  self.initialize = function ()
  {
        self.htmlTemplate(`
          <p data-deId="de-box-5" data-bind="html: myViewModel().getDynamicContent()">
            Initial content
          </p>
        `);
  };

  self.getDynamicContent = function()
  {
     return "dynamic content";
  };

  return self;
};

const vm = myViewModel();
const root = $('.xyz-template');

ko.applyBindings(vm, root[0]);
vm.initialize();

const templateHolder = root.find('p');
ko.cleanNode(templateHolder[0]);
ko.applyBindings(vm, templateHolder[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="xyz-template" data-bind="html: htmlTemplate"></div>
```

Keep in mind that in your particular case you cannot rebind root because everytime you initialize binding `html` binding from `xyz` `div` kicks in, so again `<p>` is somehow *detached*

Here you will also find better ways to solve that problem [knockout custom html binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817710/knockout-custom-html-binding)

Code which I posted is just to show the concept